# How can I run multiple Skype accounts in one computer?

Tags: skype

I would like to run multiple Skype accounts in one computer at the same time. Is there an option to do that?

It is just to separate personal Skype from business Skype.

Comment: Not possible without logging out logging in.

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want one of those to. The manual way or automated way?

Comment: What about the http://download.cnet.com/Multi-Skype-Launcher/3000-2349_4-75914456.html

Comment: Is this working right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run your first instance as usual, by clicking the icon.

Run the second one from terminal;

```
sudo /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype /secondary
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on [this page](http://www.skaip.org/command-line-parameters-for-the-new-skype).  The command line arguments still exist, they have just been changed.  Copying the format from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/803469), we have the following command:

```
open -na /Applications/Skype.app --args --secondary --datapath="/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Application\ Support/Skype2"
```

Replace "Skype2" with as many numbers as you need instances of skype and go nuts.

Answer (score -3):

In the Run window, type the following command (including the quotes) and press OK:
For 32-bit operating systems:

"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary

For 64-bit operating systems:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
If you get an error message, copy and paste the exact command from this page and try again.

Be aware that if you’ve changed the installation path for Skype, then you’ll need to enter the correct path for the Skype.exe file.

If the above solution fails, you can try another option:

Find the Skype.exe file in C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\ if you’re running a 32-bit operating system.
If you’re running 64-bit operating system, you can find the file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone.

Right-click the file and select Send to > Desktop (create shortcut).
Locate the shortcut on your desktop, then right-click it and select Properties.
In the Target field of the Shortcut tab, add /secondary to the end of the path. The Target field should now be "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary.
Click OK. You can now start a new instance of Skype every time you double-click the new shortcut.

Comment: In OS X this won't help much.

Comment: That's right, as this is an Apple based forum, this won't help much.