# How to run secondary Skype after recent Microsoft update?

Tags: windows, skype

After an update from Microsoft, `/secondary` Skype stopped working as mentioned in [How can I run multiple Skype accounts in one computer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125978/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-in-one-computer). I think they willfully want only one Skype should be working on a desktop.

The only one way I've found to run multiple Skype instances now is to just install the old classic Skype.

Is there any way to do it for new Skype?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple Skype accounts in one computer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125978/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-in-one-computer)

Comment: Don‘t just say it‘s not a duplicate. What did you try, how exactly did it fail?

Comment: I tried with /secondary option after skype exe command and it is not working. Hence it is different. You can find answer now as given by Ian and me. @patrix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading Ian's answer, I find it is a great solution to this my question. I am posting my own answer just to share my findings based on Ian's link as I faced difficulty on using above answer's path and settings.

- Copy the skype shortcut paste thereon to create new skype shortcut.
- Rename it as you want just to distinguish from the primary shortcut.
- Now, go to its properties and append following string in Target
  property
- Skype --secondary --datapath="C:\Login_1"
- Hence the new full string will be "C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe" Skype --secondary
  --datapath="C:\Login_1"
- Click on this shortcut and you are done.

Comment: Don’t think this will work on macOS :-)

Comment: Yup! I think for Mac solution Ian's answer is ok

Comment: It seems that with this solution, Skype ask to configure mic and webcam at each re-start...

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer on [this page](http://www.skaip.org/command-line-parameters-for-the-new-skype).  The command line arguments still exist, they have just been changed.  Copying the format from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/803469), we have the following command:

```
open -na /Applications/Skype.app --args --secondary --datapath="/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Application\ Support/Skype2"
```

Replace "Skype2" with as many numbers as you need instances of skype and go nuts.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I create a `Skype_old.command` file, give it execute permission and now we just need to click on it to open another Skype. Sweet